# Smoke from one of the acid holes of the battery

Tags: battery

I have a car that I don't drive frequently, so once or twice times per week I turn on the car, but sometimes I can't turn on the car so, the battery is discharged because of the time not being turned on

I took the battery to a car battery service to see if the battery can be charged again, the person that checked the battery oppened all the acid holes and connected an analogic device to the battery terminals, turned on this device, after that, did it again and this person told that the battery is dead, I asked him why and he told me to watch one of the acid holes and I saw I little smoke comes from that hole

Is that a sign of a damaged battery?

As I said this car most of the time is not used and the battery is like three? years old, since then I drive the car when it needs gasoline

Comment: It means one or more cells in the battery are very low on water, stop using it or risk an Explosion, seriously, replace the battery now.

Answer (score 2):

You need a new battery , it does not make any difference how old or how much you used the present battery. I have seen a single bad cell put out steam , I forget if  it was charging or discharging . The steam likely contains sulfuric acid , be sure to rinse off any location it may have settled.